# Primefaces component library in IntelliJ IDEA 11

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete, intellij-idea

Is it possible to add the Primefaces component library to IntelliJ IDEA 11 so I can use autocompletion on those tags too? In Eclipse it automatically supports this, but I don't know why it does so or how it works so I am not able to fix this.

Here are two images on how it looks:

[image]

[image]

---

**UPDATE and FIX**
In order to fix this you have to go to `project settings | libraries` and then add the component library.

Comment: It's better to ask from Jetbrains community, they respond very frequent :) http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/idea/ideacommunity

Comment: Did you try click Ctrl+Enter when your cursor on xmlns:p declaration? There should be smt like download scheme.

Comment: You mean Alt+Enter. I tried that now, fetching it as an external resource but it did not work :(

Comment: @user626912, off course, Alt+Enter. I believe there is some issue in this case, like proxy configuration or smt like that.

Comment: No, I fixed it: see updated question :)

Comment: @user626912 Can you please provide an answer to your question and accept it?  This will be for the benefit of future people who have the same question.

Answer (score 8):

Set your cursor on the "http://primefaces.org/ui" text and ATL+ENTER. Choose 'Manually setup external resource'. 'Map External Resources' popup will appear. Choose 'Explorer' tab and select 'primefaces-p.taglib.xml' from primefaces.jar file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a technology (I think it's called - might be a facet).

When you create a Web Module Project, you have the option of selecting additional technologies. JSF is an option for Web. Under the JSF node is a sub-node with 4 faces technologies - one of which is `Primefaces` *(others are IronFaces, RichFaces, and another)*.

When you select the required support option, IntelliJ IDEA will download the required libraries and add them to an existing or new lib.

I believe this functionality is only available in the full version; i.e., not Community Edition.

Answer (score 0):

To add primefaces to your project in Intellij, add the dependency i.e

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
   <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
   <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

to your pom.xml. and compile your project.
After that, add primefaces URI to the list of tags usable on that page such as `xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"` and you will be fine.